Created scheduled backups using Spanner's new built-in feature don't trigger the actual backup
I'm testing the new feature in Spanner to have scheduled backups. I've created several, some manually, and some through our Terraform automation.
I have a schedule that should create incremental backups (using Enterprise Tier) every night, and at the same time I have a test schedule doing the same every night for full backups.
This was configured yesterday, so I was expecting to see the first backups this morning, but there's nothing there, not even in the audit logs.
In the UI, the schedules are there, and everything seems correct, it's just that don't do anything.
Am I missing something here?
These are pictures showing a daily incremental backup that should have been triggered already.



https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/backup#backup-schedules In the doc it says "Backup schedules for newly created databases take up to 24 hours to become active and start creating backups.".
Are you by chance using a new (< day) database?

Oh, that's actually it then. These are test databases I've created at the same time as the schedule yesterday afternoon, so I will have to wait 1 more day to see it in action then. If you post your message as reply I'll mark it as the answer

From the doc:

Backup schedules for newly created databases take up to 24 hours to become active and start creating backups.

That is, if the database was created in the last day, the backup can still be in the works.
